# FIle permission error in delayed job rails in elasticbeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I have some secrect files which I want to store in the home directory and access them in delayedjob. I'm getting `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen` error when I tried to read the file through delayedjob. But, `File.read('file_path')` works properly in rails console. I gave 777 permission for the file and tried, but getting the same error.

Why am I getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: check file owner and group using shell command `ls -l file.txt`

Comment: @MoamenNaanou I tried by changing the file owner and group. But the question here is, why am I not  able to access even though the file permission is 777?